# Complex Views containing multiple Partial Views in ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a following form:

[image: design]

Edit is some partial view _Edit with separate view model called EditVM.

Search is a partial view _Search split between two another partial models - filter (_SearchFilter) and search results (_SearchResults). All those views share one view model SearchVM.

Finally I'm trying to make an UpdateVM which represents what's on the picture. It contains EditVM and SearchVM instances.

My problem is loosing information about the UpdateVM.

First I'm calling get action Update.

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Update()
{
    var model = new UpdateVM();

    var searchVM = new SearchVM();
    model.searchVM = searchVM;

    var editVM = new EditVM();
    model.editVM = editVM;

    return View(model);
}
```

View looks like that:

```
@model UpdateVM

@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views._Search, Model.searchVM)

@Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views._Edit, Model.editVM)
```

Problem begins with searching on the filter. As you can see to the _Search partial view only a SearchVM is passed. I want Search to be generic, shared between the views, so I can't pass to it the UpdateVM.

Filter view _SearchFilter looks as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.SearchButtonAction, Model.SearchButtonController, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="frm_row">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Query)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

The problem is that post action is getting SearchVM instance, moreover with only Query field set. Is it possible at all to split whole view shown on the picture only between two actions, get and post, with UpdateVM? Is it possible to don't loose the information already stored in the models (search has some settings, for example mode small or big)?

Or maybe there's other way to implement mentioned view in a robust way? Maybe I'm trying to do it not in the MVC style?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to load your partial views into the main view.  you want them to be dynamically loaded based on the search parameters.  To do this use an ajax call

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSearch', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Search", "Controller")',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: { id: $("#Query").val() },
        success: function(result){
            $(".divSearch").html(result);
        } 
    });
});
```

your controller would look like this

```
public PartialViewResult Search(int id){
    var Model = //populate the model based on the selected id
    return PartialView("_partialName", Model);
}
```

and change your search button to

```
<input type="button" value="Search" class="btnSearch" />
```

you don't want to submit the form so you want a button instead of a submit and you need to add a class to the button that your script can trigger off of for the click event.  Let me know if you have any questions.